# Custom MapBox Icons in React without geojson

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I am trying to create custom icons for my map markers in my mapbox in React, however essentially all of the existing documentation describes how to accomplish this when you are using a geojson wrapper to define a set amount of markers. This solution doesn't work for me, since the amount of markers for this application needs to be dynamic.

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(droneIconSVG.svg)';
    el.style.width = "50000px";
    el.style.height = "50000px";

    console.log(el.style.backgroundImage);
    console.log(image01);

    var drones = {};



    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("drones")
      .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

        var drone = new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat([snapshot.val().lat, snapshot.val().lng]).addTo(map);

        drones[snapshot.val().id] = drone;
      });
```

This code shows the creation of a marker, and assignment of that marker to every "drone" icon that has been added to my real time database in firebase. Any ideas as to why it might not be representing my "droneIconSVG.svg" file properly? It is a normal SVG file that I exported from illustrator.

Thank you